# Overwrite array of objects by another without affecting first's order

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, lodash

I have two arrays of objects as follows:

```
var listA = [
    { name: 'monday', reported: '', closed: '' },
    { name: 'tuesday', reported: '', closed: '' },
    { name: 'wednesday', reported: '', closed: '' },
    { name: 'thursday', reported: '', closed: '' },
    { name: 'friday', reported: '', closed: '' },
    { name: 'saturday', reported: '', closed: '' },
    { name: 'sunday', reported: '', closed: '' }
];

var listB = [
    { name: 'friday', reported: '23', closed: '17' },
    { name: 'tuesday', reported: '28', closed: '24' },
    { name: 'saturday', reported: '10', closed: '8' },
];
```

I want to overwrite listA by values from listB without affecting order of objects in listA. I tried it with _.unionBy[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pv2wb/121/). It gives result as follows:

```
{name: "friday", reported: "23", closed: "17"}
{name: "tuesday", reported: "28", closed: "24"}
{name: "saturday", reported: "10", closed: "8"}
{name: "monday", reported: "", closed: ""}
{name: "wednesday", reported: "", closed: ""}
{name: "thursday", reported: "", closed: ""}
{name: "sunday", reported: "", closed: ""}
```

I am expecting following result:

```
{name: "monday", reported: "", closed: ""}
{name: "tuesday", reported: "28", closed: "24"}
{name: "wednesday", reported: "", closed: ""}
{name: "thursday", reported: "", closed: ""}
{name: "friday", reported: "23", closed: "17"}
{name: "saturday", reported: "10", closed: "8"}
{name: "sunday", reported: "", closed: ""}
```

I know how I can do it by iterating over `listA` and replacing the values from `listB` with same `name`. However wondering if there is any better way of doing this by lodash or ES6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `map` (so that array doesn't have to be mutated) and `find`

```
var listC = listA.map( s => 
     Object.assign( {}, s, 
      listB.find( s1 => s1.name == s.name ) ) );
```

**Demo**

```js
var listA = [
    { name: 'monday', reported: '', closed: '' },
    { name: 'tuesday', reported: '', closed: '' },
    { name: 'wednesday', reported: '', closed: '' },
    { name: 'thursday', reported: '', closed: '' },
    { name: 'friday', reported: '', closed: '' },
    { name: 'saturday', reported: '', closed: '' },
    { name: 'sunday', reported: '', closed: '' }
];

var listB = [
    { name: 'friday', reported: '23', closed: '17' },
    { name: 'tuesday', reported: '28', closed: '24' },
    { name: 'saturday', reported: '10', closed: '8' },
];

var listC = listA.map( s => 
     Object.assign( {}, s, 
      listB.find( s1 => s1.name == s.name ) ) );

console.log( listC );
```

Comment: I'm wondering if there is any reason in writing `Object.assign( {}, s, listB.find( s1 => s1.name == s.name ) )` instead `Object.assign( s, listB.find( s1 => s1.name == s.name ) )`

Comment: @Arkej Probably because that will modify the listA array